# Netlify restrictions on environment variable size

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, serverless, netlify

As I understand it, Netlify Environment Variables have some restrictions on size. Looking into it, they use AWS under the hood and are subject to the same restrictions [as this service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console). Most notably:

- Keys can contain up to 128 characters. Values can contain up to 256 characters.
- The combined size of all environment properties cannot exceed 4,096 bytes when stored as strings with the format key=value.

I'm passing JWT keys to my serverless functions via environment variables in Netlify. The keys in question (particularly the private key) are long enough to flout these restrictions. My private key is at least 3K characters; well over the 256 outlined above.

How have others managed to get round this issue? Is there another way to add lengthy keys without having to include them in your codebase?

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* store those keys in the environment variables. Even though environment variables can be encrypted, for sensitive information like this I would not recommend using it. There are two possible solutions I can think of.

**Solution 1**

Use *AWS Systems Manager (SSM)*. Specifically, you should use the [parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html). There you can create key-value pairs like your environment variables and they can be marked as "SecureString", so they are encrypted.

Then you use the AWS SDK to read the value from SSM in your application.

One benefit of this approach is, that you can use IAM to restrict access to those SSM parameters and make sure that only trusted people/applications have access. If you use environment variables, you can not separately manage access to those values.

**Solution 2**

As far as I am aware, those keys must be coming from somewhere. Typically, there are "key endpoints" from whatever authentication provider you use (e.g. Auth0, Okta). In your application you could get the keys from the endpoint using a HTTP call and then cache them in your application for a while, to avoid unnecessary HTTP requests.

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to manage those keys yourself. When they change for whatever reason, you will not need to change anything/deploy anything to make your application work with the new keys. Although this should not happen too often, so it is still reasonable from my point of view to "hardcode" the keys in SSM.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here, but there's now a build plugin that allows inlining of extra-long environment variables for use in Netlify functions.

There's a tutorial here:  https://ntl.fyi/3Ie1MXH

And you can find the build plugin and docs here: https://github.com/bencao/netlify-plugin-inline-functions-env

If your environment variable needs to preserve new lines (such as in the case of a private key), you’ll need do something like this on the environment variable:

```
process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")
```

Other than that, it worked a treat for me!